# Show div on only one WHILE Loop result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a while loop that shows the results from a select query. Then for each result that was returned by the query, there is a link that once clicked, will show a message form. Clicking again the link, the message form will be hidden. It was made using a JQuery plugin. The problem now is, if I clicked the link, all the results will show the message form instead of showing only one, which should be from the result where the link was clicked. The code looks like this:

PHP + HTML

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query(......) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row['Id'];
        echo "<a class='hideMessageForm' href='#foo?id=" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a>" .       
       "<div id='foo' class='showMessageForm'>
           <form action='process.php' method='post'>
              <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" .$id "'/>
              <input type='text' name='message' value=''/>
              <input type='submit' name='sendMessage' value='Send Message'/>
           </form>
       </div>";
    }
?>
```

JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".showMessageForm").hide();
    $(".hideMessageForm").show();

    $('.hideMessageForm').click(function(){
    $(".showMessageForm").slideToggle();
    });

 });
```

Let me explain the thing I want to happen

For example, the query returned 3 results (result #1, #2, #3). Each result shows the link that refers to the foo div. If I clicked the link in result #1, the #2 and #3 will also popup the message form. Clicking the link from any of the 3 results will show 3 message form. I only want the result where the link was selected to be the only one to popup the message form. Thank you!

Comment: maybe use .remove before another link is clicked?

Comment: @RPM how? sorry I am very new to Jquery.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to get at here. You generate a long series of `<a>` tags with ID numbers pulled from the database. then output a form with an ID pulled from the query string? How do those two relate to each other?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Are you saying that when you click on a popup, it shows ALL results and not just the one for the link? If so - it sounds like a PHP error. Or, are you saying you only want ONE of the links to be able to be clicked at a time? If you could link a live example it might be helpful.

Comment: is your data going into showMessageForm once the link is clicked? And it is overalapping itself with the previous clicked data right? then just add this right after the click)function() $('.showMessageForm').remove();

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? From your code, it looks there is only one form being outputted, not one per result.

Comment: Once the a link was clicked, the showMessageForm will show

Comment: For example, the query returned 3 results. Each of those 3 results shows the LINK that refers to the foo div. If i clicked the link from result# 1, the result #2 and #3 will also popup the showMessageForm. I want the result# selected to be the only one to popup the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/qEeZf/

You are displaying / hidding all elements of the class. You just want to display or hide the next element of the link clicked. ( Seeing your PHP code, I am assuming the div will always be the next element after the link).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".showMessageForm").hide();
    $(".hideMessageForm").show();

    $('.hideMessageForm').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".showMessageForm").slideToggle();
    });

 });
```

Comment: After I replaced my code with yours, the form is now always on display, can't be hidden. the link also disappeared.

Comment: Check the working demo on the jsfiddle link that I posted. Is that you wanted right?

Comment: Also, the id to be assigned is dynamically inserted. It's on a while loop.

Comment: Yes this was just a sample output what your PHP code would generate. I have just replaced the PHP variables with HTML to simulate the outputted HTML code from your PHP.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comments. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much! I really appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

The php/mysql (you've got a few errors in how the php/html is formatted. I corrected them.)

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query(......) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row['Id'];
    echo "<a class='hideMessageForm' href='#foo" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a>" .       
   "<div id='foo" . $row['Id'] . "'' class='showMessageForm'>
       <form action='process.php' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['Id'] . "'/>
          <input type='text' name='message' value=''/>
          <input type='submit' name='sendMessage' value='Send Message'/>
       </form>
   </div>";
}
?>
```

the jquery.....

```
$(".hideMessageForm").click(function() {
var dropD = $(this).attr("href");
if ($(dropD + ".opened").length) { 
$(".opened").slideToggle(300).removeClass("opened");
} else {
$(".opened").slideToggle(300).removeClass("opened");
$(dropD).slideToggle(300).addClass("opened");
}   
return false;
});
```

css...

```
.showMessageForm { display: none;}
.opened { display: block; }
```

And a Live [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BEEF9/1/)

Comment: I used your code, but clicking the link doesn't show the message form

Comment: Check your php/html formatting. As I posted, you've got several errors there. And interesting.. liked my coe.. but gave the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<form action='process.php' method='post'>
              <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id".'/> // Here was error 
              <input type='text' name='message' value=''/>
              <input type='submit' name='sendMessage' value='Send Message'/>
</form>"
```

Comment: Please don't mind that, it works perfectly for me. only a typo error.